# Android: Locations of super() calls in Widgets

Tags: java, android, widget

When creating own Widget class, we are overriding some of the basic `AppWidgetProvider` methods:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(final Context context)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onEnabled(context);
}
@Override
public void onDeleted(final Context context, final int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
@Override
public void onDisabled(final Context context)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Does it perform any pre-processing when we call `super()` at the end or start?

Is there a rule/explanation when to call `super()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AppWidgetProvider` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java) is just a `BroadcastReceiver` with a specialized `onReceive()` method that delegates incoming broadcasts to the other methods based on the action. The `onEnabled()`, `onDeleted()`, `onDisabled()`, and `onUpdate()` methods are all empty in the `AppWidgetProvider` class, so there's no need to call the `super` method in any of those.

You don't need to override `onReceive()` at all, and can just handle your widget's functionalities in the other provided methods. If you intend to override the `onReceive()` method and handle everything yourself - that is, check the action, and act accordingly in each case - then you can omit the `super` call there as well. If you're going to "go halfway", and just handle some actions directly, then you just need to call `super.onReceive()` when appropriate, as all it's really going to do is immediately call one of the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `super` keyword you're calling the superclass implementation of the particular method.

Where you should place your code compared to the super call depends on when you would like it to run, before or after the superclass implementation.

In case of `onEnabled()`, `onDisabled()` and `onDeleted()` and `onUpdate()`, it doesn't matter, they are empty methods in the superclass, you don't even need to call them.

`onReceive()` is basically a dispatcher that calls all the other methods of the class, based on the received action. If you would like to do that yourself, don't call it. If you do not, call it when it's appropriate for the other methods to be called, depending on your needs.